# Rails: How to add external link to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a string in which users input a URL, which is later displayed in index.html.  How can I turn that into a working external link?  Right now, the link displays as should (e.g. www.facebook.com/tester), but when I click on the link I get a no route matches "/www.facebook.com/tester" routing error.  I tried user.facebook.link but that didn't work.

I tried adding href=" " also but with no luck.

```
<%= link_to nil, user.facebook %>
```

Comment: the error message said no route matches what?

Comment: @Andy no route matches "/www.facebook.com/tester". I assuming Rails thinks that the link belongs to an internal route.  However, that's not what I am looking for.  The link should go to another site, in this case Facebook.

Comment: If it doesn't include the "http://" part it'll think it's a relative link. Why not just use a normal `<a ...>` tag or a helper that wraps one up?

Comment: @DaveNewton Don't I need the <% %> for embedded ruby to displayed the string that they inputted?

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean you need to use a link helper (though you probably can). I keep them separate to avoid cognitive overhead (in general). `<a href="http://facebook.../<%= user.facebook %>">Go to facebook</a>`

Comment: Or add the `http://` part in the `link_to` helper: `<%= link_to nil, "http://#{user.facebook}" %>`.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for all the help! Last thing, what if the inputs are EITHER http:// links (e.g. http:// www.facebook...) or just the domain without the http:// (e.g. www.facebook...) in front?  Only one type of the links will work.  Is there a way around it which allows both types? I know this may be asking a lot, but it's okay if you don't know it or don't have time to reply.

Comment: You should be scrubbing/normalizing earlier in the process. Since you're not, we're back to a helper our method that wraps the url variable to normalize it, or a helper that wraps link_to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @Mischa, you can add:

```
<%=link_to nil, "http://#{user.facebook}"%>
```

to have the protocol added to link.

If you need to give the link a label, say, `Facebook`, you can use it:

```
<%=link_to 'Facebook', "http://#{user.facebook}"%>`
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: What if the the input varied from domains with "http:" and ones that began with "www"? The "http:" would add another "http:" to some domains and not work.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can use scan method to check whether "http" is contained or not. For eg: `user.facebook.scan(\^http\)` should return an empty array if the string does not start with http.